# For two correlated r.v. $X$ and $Y$, is there a function $f$ such that $\text{variance}(XY) \leq f(\text{variance}(X),\text{variance}(Y))$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two correlated random variables. Is there a function $f$ such that $\text{variance}(XY) \leq f(\text{variance}(X),\text{variance}(Y))$??

(I know $X$ is bounded, i.e. there is a constant $C$ such that $|X| < C.$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Not even if $\mathrm{E}[X], \mathrm{E}[Y]$ was known, or even zero.

Let $U$ have the distribution $f(u)=4/u^5$ for $u\ge1$: this is a Pareto distribution. Then $\mathrm{E}[U]=4/3$ and $\mathrm{Var}[U]=2/9$: the critical thing is that they are both finite. *NB: I previously messed up the integrals, which I have now tried to correct.*

However, $\mathrm{E}[U^4]$ is infinite.

So, if you let $X=Y=aU-b$ for appropriate $a,b$, you can get $\mathrm{E}[X]=\mathrm{E}[Y]$ and $\mathrm{Var}[X]=\mathrm{Var}[Y]$ to take any pair of values, but $\mathrm{Var}[XY]$ will be infinite.